# Rosalind's - 'Ordering Strings of Varying Length Lexicographically' Is it possible to sort my result?

Tags: python, string, combinations, rosalind

I tried to solve another of Rosalind(http://rosalind.info/problems/lexv/) problems by myself, however unfortunately I have to ask you for help.

Here is **my approach**:

First of all; function which creates all possible substrings of input string with length of n:

```
def get_substrings(input_string, l):
res_list = []
sub = []
for i in range(len(input_string)):
    if l+i <= len(input_string):
        for j in range(i,l+i):
            sub.append(input_string[j])
    sub = ''.join(sub)
    res_list.append(sub)
    sub = []
res_list = filter(None, res_list)
return res_list
```

Then main function which creates all combinations of current string with varying length:

```
from itertools import product
def lexv():
dna = str(raw_input())
n = int(raw_input())
subs = get_substrings(dna, n)
result = []
for i in range(len(subs)):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        result = result + list(product(dna, repeat=j))
for i in range(len(result)):
     result[i]  = "".join(result[i])
     print result[i]
```

The result of my code for data from Rosalind's 'Sample input' is:

```
D
N
A
DD
DN
DA
ND
NN
NA
AD
AN
AA
DDD
DDN
DDA
DND
DNN
DNA
DAD
DAN
DAA
NDD
NDN
NDA
NND
NNN
NNA
NAD
NAN
NAA
ADD
ADN
ADA
AND
ANN
ANA
AAD
AAN
AAA
```

**My questions:**

a) Is it possible to order my result as it should be (Rosalind's result)?

b) Is my approach correct? If not, could you give me some clue (**but not the solution** for this problem - I'd like to beat it by myself).

**Very thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Generating possible substrings

For the generation of possible substrings, I would look deeper into the `itertools` module. With `chain` and `product` you can easily make a one-lines that returns all combinations

## Sorting

for the sorting, I would replace the letters themselves with `int`s, keeping this translation table in a `dict`. `enumerate` and `str.split` are your friends here.

Now you have a list of tuples of ints, which you can sort. From what I can tell, the standard sorting order of tuples is useful.

When you have a sorted list of tuples, you will just need to do the backwards translation to strings

### sorted(key=)

Another option is to use standard string sorting, and as `key=` argument to `sorted`, passing a function (or lambda) which replaces each letter in the string to it's place in the alphabet (the `input_string`)

This can be done with [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), `enumerate` and a `dict` comprehension

Comment: If you want a peak at my solutions, you can check [github](https://github.com/vadella/StackOverflow-questions/blob/master/Rosalind%20lexical%20sorting.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for your effort (github solutions) and clues, now it looks clear for me.